# Leonardo Da Vinci's Magic Calendar

Tags: mathematics, magic

It is the year 1468 and young Da Vinci has built a magic calendar going back to Jesus. Here's how it works: Given 7 distinct years between 33 and 1468 inclusive, the arranger discards one and orders the remaining years. Given a list of 6 years, the magic selector picks a year between 33 and 1468 inclusive, perhaps not on the list.

What's so magic about this? Remarkably, the year which is discarded is always the same as the year which is selected. Furthermore, the calendar never cheats since the selector has no way of knowing what just got discarded. Can you figure out how he did this?

Note: The last question is somewhat rhetorical, any method which works qualifies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The magic is that Leonardo knows

> [The Factorial Number System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system)

In fact Leonardo has obtained just part of a magic calendar from the year

> 5045 which given seven years between 0 and 5045 inclusive does the same trick.

To design an arranger, we write the years in order $y_0,\ldots, y_6$ and discard

> $y_i$ where $i\equiv y_0+\cdots y_6\pmod 7$. The selector sees values $x_0,\ldots, x_5$ and can add these mod 7 to get a value $s$. They then know that either 0) the discarded year is in the interval $[0,x_0)$ and is congruent to $-s\pmod 7$ or 1) the discarded card in the interval $(x_0,x_1)$ and is congruent to $1-s\pmod 7$ or ... 6) the discard card lies in the interval $(x_5,5045]$ and is congruent to $6-s\pmod 7$. This is a total of $(5046-6)/7=6!$ possible discarded values.

The arranger can unambiguously communicate the precise value from this set by arranging the cards

> to communicate a number in the base factorial system. To communicate the number $c_55!+c_44!+\cdots+c_11!$ the arranger chooses the first card to be $c_5$th card of the six undiscarded cards in size order, the second to be the fifth card of the five remaining cards in size order and so on.

The selector can recover this by

> counting how many cards are less than the first card to recover $c_5$, counting how many cards other than the first are less than the second to recover $c_5$ and so on.

For example, suppose the arrange is given the values

> `[430, 1362, 4420, 1095, 3047, 1001, 756]` which when sorted are `[430, 756, 1001, 1095, 1362, 3047, 4420]`. The sum of these values is 12111 which 1 mod 7 and so the arranger discards 756 leaving `[430, 1001, 1095, 1362, 3047, 4420]` which sum to 11355 which is 1 mod 7. There are 61 numbers in the interval $[0,430)$ that are 6 mod 7, 81 numbers in the interval $(430,1001)$ that are 0 mod 7, 14 valid discards in the interval $(1001,1095)$, 38 valid discards in the range $(1095 , 1362)$, 240 valid discards in the range $(1362,3047)$, 196 valid discards in the interval $(3047,4420)$ and 90 valid discards in the range $(4420,5045]$. Of the 720 valid discards, 756 is the 107th. Writing 107 in the factorial number system, we have $107=0(5!)+4(4!)+1(3!)+2(2!)+1(1!)$ so that the arranger puts the remaining years in the order `[430,4420,1095,3047,1362,1001]`.

Here's some python:

> ```
>  from math import factorial
>  from random import randint
>
>  def arranger(years):
>      years.sort()
>      index = sum (y for y in years)%7
>      discard = years[index]
>      years.remove(discard)
>      syndrome = -sum(y for y in years)%7
>      position = (discard-index-syndrome)//7
>      answer = []
>      for i in range(5,0,-1):
>          nxt = position//factorial(i)
>          answer += [years[nxt]]
>          years.remove(years[nxt])
>          position -= nxt*factorial(i)
>      answer += [years[0]]
>      return answer, discard
>
>  message,discard=arranger([430, 1362, 4420, 1095, 3047, 1001, 756])
>
>  print(message)
>
>  def selector(years):
>      position = 0
>      for i in range(5):
>          coeff = 0
>          for j in range(i,6):
>              if years[j]<years[i]:
>                  coeff += 1
>          position += coeff*factorial(5-i)
>      syndrome = -sum(y for y in years)%7
>      val = 7*position+syndrome
>      years.sort()
>      for y in years:
>          if y <= val:
>              val += 1
>      return val
>
>  print(selector(message))
>
>  for i in range(10000):
>      check = [randint(0,5045) for j in range(7) ]
>      while(len(set(check))<7):
>          check = [randint(0,5045) for j in range(7) ]
>      sanity = check.copy()
>      message,discard = arranger(check)
>      answer = selector(message)
>      if answer !=discard:
>          print("Exception!")
>          print(sanity,discard,answer)
> ```